# Laravel PHPUnit PDOException exception

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-testing

I don't know why when I run a PHPUnit test, I get the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

My testing environment database setting is:

```
return [

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    'default' => 'mysql',

    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'clg_test',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'veryHardPass',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ]
    ],

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

];
```

The reason why I am using MySQL as oppose to SQLite is because my migration files use `dropColumn` which is not supported by SQLite. I call the migration via `Artisan::call('migrate')` in the setup.

If I actually call migration manually in the terminal via `php artisan migrate --env=testing` then the migration IS successful and the databases are created.

Why am I then facing the above problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. The message you're getting is indicative of the script not being able to connect to MySQL through a socket, but using an ip should work.

Comment: Thanks, so now I am getting a connection refused error!

Comment: Well, that's a start... :) unfortunately, I don't know what might cause that. I hope you find the error.